# Как будет выглядеть аналог функции на D7?

Tags: php, битрикс

Как переписать сию конструкцию на D7?
Не судите строго, Битрикс осваиваю только...

```
$dbBasketItems = CSaleBasket::GetList(
                array("NAME" => "ASC"),
                array("ORDER_ID" => $orderID),
                false,
                false,
                array("PRODUCT_ID", "ID", "NAME", "QUANTITY", "PRICE", "CURRENCY")
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для D7 получить корзину текущего пользователя так

```
$basket = Sale\Basket::loadItemsForFUser(Sale\Fuser::getId(), Bitrix\Main\Context::getCurrent()->getSite());
```

А вобще рекомендую вам ознакомится этим [материалом](https://mrcappuccino.ru/blog/post/work-with-basket-bitrix-d7)

Comment: Спасибо, уже ознакомился) все оказалось проще, чем казалось